# Find quadratic equation based on 2 tangents

Tags: calculus, quadratics

I would like to know a way to find an quadratic equation that had 2 given tangents:

For example here is 2 tangents equations:

- y = 1/2 x
- y = 2 x + 2

and 2 abscisses

- x = 0
- x = 3

Is there a simple way to find a quadratic equation that saitisfies those two tangents at respective abscisses?

I'm working in Clojure if it needs to be computer related

Sorry for my bad english

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mathematics. Questions on Stackoverflow should be at least tangentially related to computer programming.

Comment: I have flagged it for moderator attention.

Comment: You should be a bit more clear: exactly what do you mean by 'quadratic equation', and what do you mean by an equation 'satisfying a tangent'?

Comment: In comments below you say you are looking for a parabola, and not just any quadratic equation. Do you have any limitations or preferences on the kind of a parabola, for example if its axis should be parallel to the X or Y axis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the little that you provide, I infer that you are looking for a parabola equation of the form

```
y = A x^2 + B x + C
```

tangent to the two lines at the given abscissas.

The slope is given by

```
y' = 2 A x + b
```

Expressing the equal slope conditions, we have

```
2 A 0 + B = 1/2
2 A 3 + B = 2
```

giving `A = 1/4`, `B = 1/2`.

Expressing the equal ordinate conditions, we have

```
A 0^2 + B 0 + C = 0 / 2
A 3^2 + B 3 + C = 2 3 + 2
```

leading to `9/4 + 3/2 = 8` !!!

There is no solution, as there are too many constraints.

Answer (score 3):

Given that:

```
y = 1/2 x         <=>    1/2 x - y = 0
y = 2 x + 2       <=>    2 x + 2  - y = 0
```

Therefore

```
(1/2 x - y)(2 x + 2  - y) = 0
```

is one quadratic equation that has these two lines as tangents. In fact, if you plot its solutions you'll find they consist of the two lines.

Comment: Yes, I realised the wording was unclear.

Comment: Although your answer is technically correct, I suspect the OP is actually looking for parabolae! :)

Comment: yes i'm searching for a parabolae, maybe i can specify my question by giving the abscisses at wich the parabolae is tangent to those linear equations